# What is the meaning of "$fg$ has constant sign a.e."?

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

What is the meaning of "$f$g has constant sign a.e." for question 4 on page 143 of Wheeden & Zygmund's Measure and Integral?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that $fg$ is either positive a.e., or negative a.e..

(In other words, either the complement of the set $\{x\in X: fg(x)>0\}$ has measure zero, or the complement of the set $\{x\in X:fg(x)<0\}$ has measure zero.)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Really thanks for your help! :D